# What Tables or Views for ORA- errors?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, audit-trail

I need some help in auditing in Oracle. We have a database with many tables and we want to be able to audit every change made to any table in any field. However, I find it difficult to locate the descriptions for ERROR code. For example,

So my question is which table or view holds these messages all together.

Comment: What's the relation between auditing changes and error codes?

Answer (score 0):

oerr - Oracle error messages, is a utility (script not an executable) which comes with unix and linux based oracle installations and can be found in the bin directory. Input to this script could be the error code.

this utility extracts error messages with suggested actions from the standard Oracle message files

Just because it uses awk functionalities, it is not supported in windows.

Usage details : http://www.oracledistilled.com/oracle-database/troubleshooting/using-the-oerr-utility-to-aid-in-error-investigation/l

SQLERRM and SQLCODE functions extract error messages and error codes, but it returns value only inside the exception handler and not in any SQLs, outside them, it always return success message!

So, I doubt if there is a possible solution for what you ask.

Comment: outside of an exception handler, `SQLERRM(<code>)` is a function that returns an error message for a given code - e.g. `SQLERRM(-942)`